# putting cbuuid into nsdata?

Tags: ios, nsdata

I am trying to put a cbuuid string into an nsdata, but i can't find the right method. Here are some of the things I have tried:

```
//NSData* UUIDsKey_data = [[NSData alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString: @GENERIC_SYSTEM_DEVICE_SERVICES_UUID_iOS ]]];

    //NSData* UUIDsKey_data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[CBUUID UUIDWithString: @GENERIC_SYSTEM_DEVICE_SERVICES_UUID_iOS ]];

    //NSData* UUIDsKey_data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[CBUUID UUIDWithString: @GENERIC_SYSTEM_DEVICE_SERVICES_UUID_iOS ]];

   // NSData* UUIDsKey_data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString: @GENERIC_SYSTEM_DEVICE_SERVICES_UUID_iOS ]];

    //NSData* UUIDsKey_data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:[CBUUID UUIDWithString: @GENERIC_SYSTEM_DEVICE_SERVICES_UUID_iOS ]];
```

how do I convert this? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
CBUUID *guid = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@GENERIC_SYSTEM_DEVICE_SERVICES_UUID_iOS];
NSData * UUIDsKey_data = guid.data;
```

Comment: @Lal - Next time you review, scroll down a bit. You can see the question below the answer.